# Download and Load HTML file in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create a file/folder viewer and downloaded where I will be showing a network shared directory on a web page and it'll show all the contents of the share. If the file is a pdf or xls or doc it'll download and if its HTML then it'll show in an iFrame on the page.

I have achieved the first thing (downloading the files) but not able to do the 2nd part; showing the HTML file in iFrame.

When I click the HTML file it downloads like other files and I am not sure how to not download for HTML but show on screen.

The idea is to show the directory as KB where FAQ doc or pages are placed.

This is my code for download.

Javascript

```
 $('#container_id').fileTree({
    root: '<network path to load files from>',
    expandSpeed: 1000,
    collapseSpeed: 1000,
    multiFolder: true
}, function(file) {

    $("#iframe").attr("src", "/dl.aspx?file=" + file);
    $('#iframe').load();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="example">
    <h2>File List</h2>
    <div id="container_id" class="demo"></div>
    <iframe id="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

CS

```
if (Request.QueryString["file"] != null)
{
    string actualFilePath = Request.QueryString["file"].ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(actualFilePath);
    String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + filename;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(actualFilePath);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you souldn't use this `$("#iframe").attr("src", "/dl.aspx?file=" + file);` for the HTML file. By doing this you call your `dl.aspx` file who "want" download the file.

Instead, do a check :

- if the file is <> HTML, then do `$("#iframe").attr("src", "/dl.aspx?file=" + file);`
- if = HTML do `$("#iframe").attr("src", "file_path/my-html-file.html");`

Comment: your suggestion gave me an idea and I was able to achieve the functionality. What I am doing now is copying the .html file to a directory on the server and setting that URL on the iframe and its showing the file from there.

Comment: when its an .html file I do a ajax call and get the path and set to the iframe. `[WebMethod]
        public static string GetPath(string name)
        {
            string fps = name;
            string fpd = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temppage"), Path.GetFileName(fps));

            File.Copy(fps, fpd, true);
            return "/temppage/" + Path.GetFileName(fpd);
        }`